# Swapping two button controls

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Having a bit trouble trying to figure out a way to swap 2 buttons. Let just dive in and show you the code:

```
            int mCatID;
            int mTempPos;                

            mCatID = mCatButList[mValidCatNumber - 1].mCatID - 1;               

            if (mTempOldPos.ToString() != txtCatPos.Text) // Attempt to change position
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in mIMenu.mCategoryList.Rows) // Check if space is taken
                {
                    if (row[2].ToString() == txtCatPos.Text) // Space is taken
                    {
                         mCatOldIDX = mTempOldID - 2;
                        mTempDesc = mIMenu.mCategoryList.Rows[mCatOldIDX][1].ToString();

                        mIMenu.mCategoryList.Rows[mCatOldIDX][1] = row[1].ToString(); // desc
                        mIMenu.mCategoryList.Rows[mCatOldIDX][2] = (int)row[2];        // pos                     

                        row[1] = mTempDesc;
                        row[2] = mTempOldPos; //RP change new location to old   

                        mCatOldIDX = 0;

                        mIMenu.mCategoryList.AcceptChanges();

                        break;
                    }
                }
               // mIMenu.mCategoryList.DefaultView.Sort = "POS asc";

                CreateCatButList();
                DisplayMenuCategories();
```

[EDIT] I have modified the code and now it seems that it does swap the position of the button controls once. But if I swap two of the controls and then swap one of the swapped buttons with another button it seems to mess up all the position values on all of the other buttons!? This is really starting to bug me.. why does it work for the first time and then not for others? Ive tried accept changes and still no effect.. Its all to do with the value in the Datatable `mIMenu.mCategoryList` where column `[1]` is Description and `[2]` is the Position. What is frustrating is why would it work once changing the value and then as soon as the state changes to modified decides to revert back to older position values?

Comment: If you want to swap 2 button on your UI, why not just modify the location of the buttons? no need to change event linked to buttons and all

Comment: The 'pos' needs to be used in order to set the order of the buttons, as is used elsewhere. This is the backend I am trying to code, and the position is a value in the database [2] = POS :-/

Comment: Why do you need to swap the location two buttons? If you could provide some more detail on what you're trying to do, there may be a better alternative for it.

Comment: If you can imagine a 2 column grid by 8 rows in length (so its a vertical set of buttons). When a user clicks one of those the options are shown in another grid to the right of those buttons which is why I have linked it all to the 'mIMenu.mCategoryList' DataTable. All I want is when the user changes the position in a text field for that button to move to the new position.. and if that position is taken (by another button) swap the buttons instead.. the value that controls the position is `mIMenu.mCategoryList.Rows[RowIDX][2]`